Why my little monad in OCaml doesn't compile?
I'm learning Monad in OCaml, but it doesn't compile.
I reduced the code to reproduce the problem at easiest way :
file try.ml:
module type TRY = sig
  type 'a t
  val return : 'a -> 'a t
end

module Try : TRY = struct

  type 'a t = Success of 'a | Failure of exn

  let return a = Success a
end

let () =
  match Try.return 5 with
  | Try.Success a -> print_int a
  | Try.Failure e -> print_endline (Printexc.to_string e)

then I compile with :
ocamlc try.ml

and i get this error :
Error: Unbound constructor Try.Success

I found nowhere a clue to repair, I need help.

The signature constraint in
module Try : TRY = struct
   ...
end

is restraining the contents of the module accessible from outside of the module to exactly the TRY module type (aka signature constraints in OCaml erases information).
In other words, once you have constrained the module Try to TRY, you cannot longer distinguish it from any module that implement the TRY module type and thus
let () =
  match Try.return 5 with
  | Try.Success a -> print_int a
  | Try.Failure e -> print_endline (Printexc.to_string e)

fails because not all implementation of TRY define a Success variant constructor which is indeed probably not what you want.

Ok I got it,
do a signature with a monad is a bad idea
Even if i write
module Try : (TRY with type 'a t = Success of 'a | Failure of exn) = struct

the compilation fail because of the "of" which provokes a Syntax error
I just removed the signature TRY, then it works

The signature defines what is known about your Try module, yeah, so if you specify a rigid type that is all you are allowed to know.
